# How to lookup value from another table in Power Query?

Tags: join, powerbi, concatenation, powerquery, lookup

[image]

[image]

I want to transform the strategy code number in my `Strategy Code` column (`Data` table) into strategy name based on the `dim_strategy` table. My Challenge is there can be more than 1 strategy code appear in each row and hence I want to use `+` as the delimiter to combine different strategy name in `Data` table.

This is the desired output in `Data` table:

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will achieve that for you. You will need to change the source for whatever your table source is but the rest of the steps should be exactly the same.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"No.", Int64.Type}, {"Strategy Code", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Strategy Code", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Strategy Code"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Strategy Code", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type1", {"Strategy Code"}, dim_strategy, {"Strategy Code"}, "dim_strategy", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded dim_strategy" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "dim_strategy", {"Strategy"}, {"Strategy"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded dim_strategy",{"Strategy Code"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"No."}, {{"Stretagy Name", each Text.Combine([Strategy], " + "), type nullable text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could add a column

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Strategy Name", each Text.Combine(
    List.Transform(Text.Split([Strategy Code],","), each  
    dim_strategy[Strategy]{List.PositionOf(dim_strategy[Strategy Code],Number.From(_))}
),", "))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

It converts the Strategy Code to a list, then to numerical list, finds the position of that in the dim_strategy Strategy Code column, then pulls the corresponding Strategy column and recombines the list into text

List.Buffer dim_strategy2[Strategy Code] as an earlier step if dataset is large